# Links and Urls in Terminal

Tags: url, text, hyperlink, terminal

ok I have a rtf file full of links to websites.

Is there a terminal command that will simply extract the URL from the links and write it to a new file?

SO that way I will have a rtf file of raw URLs?

Comment: Can you give an example consisting of a few lines how the original file looks like and what you want the final file to look like?

Comment: say the file has a link "Google", and when its clicked the link directs the user to http://www.Google.co.uk  ... I want to take all the links from one rtf file and output all the directed urls in another.